# Is there a masked-blend instruction on PowerPC?

Tags: assembly, simd, powerpc, altivec

I'm trying to perform a masked blend (on `__vector` types) on a PowerPC (POWER 8).
When looking to the intrinsics ([list available here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.0/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/compiler_ref/vec_intrin_cpp.html)) I can see a vector select, but nothing for the merge.

On x86 processors I know the intrinsic `_mm256_blendv_ps`, and I'm looking for something similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `vec_sel` is doing exactly what I want.

```
result = vec_sel(result, src, mask);
```

I just misread the instruction set.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Another intrinsic to look at is `vec_perm` , which gives you arbitrary selection of bytes from two vectors